# My maven build is failing due to wadl-plugin issue it seems, Need help to resolve this error

Tags: maven

My maven build is failing due to wadl-plugin issue it seems, did anybody came across this issue? I donot have any clue how to fix this, Need help to resolve this error...

My JDK Version: Jdk.1.7.0_60

My Maven Version: 3.2.1

My Pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-wadl-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wadlFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.wadl</wadlFile>
                    <formatWadlFile>true</formatWadlFile>
                    <baseUri>http://&lt;HostName&gt;:&lt;port&gt;/&lt;contextname&gt; </baseUri>
                    <packagesResourceConfig>
                        <param>com.myproject.resources</param>
                    </packagesResourceConfig>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <wadlGenerators>
                        <wadlGeneratorDescription>
                            <className>
                                com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc
                            </className>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>applicationDocsFile</name>
                                    <value>${basedir}/src/main/resources/doc/application-doc.xml</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </wadlGeneratorDescription>
                        <wadlGeneratorDescription>
                            <className>
                                com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport
                            </className>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>grammarsFile</name>
                                    <value>${basedir}/src/main/resources/doc/application-grammars.xml</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </wadlGeneratorDescription>
                        <wadlGeneratorDescription>
                            <className>
                                com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.resourcedoc.WadlGeneratorResourceDocSupport
                            </className>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>resourceDocFile</name>
                                    <value>${project.build.outputDirectory}/resourcedoc.xml</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </wadlGeneratorDescription>
                        <wadlGeneratorDescription>
                            <className>
                                myProject.MyWadlGenerator
                            </className>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>resourceDocFile</name>
                                    <value>${project.build.outputDirectory}/resourcedoc.xml</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </wadlGeneratorDescription>
                    </wadlGenerators>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

**Error:**

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.sun.jersey.contribs:maven-wadl-plugin:1.8:gen erate (generate) on
>   project Myproject: Execution generate of goal com.
>   sun.jersey.contribs:maven-wadl-plugin:1.8:generate failed: **A
>   required class was missing while executing
>   com.sun.jersey.contribs:maven-wadl-plugin:1.8:generate:
>   org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory**

Thanks,
Sundar